# write textarea value to a file and upload to server in chrome or firefox(not IE)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, github-pages

I have a textarea on a website hosted by GitHub Pages as follows:

`<textarea id='text'></textarea><input type="button" onClick="Submit()"value="submit">`

Is it possible to write the value of the text area to a `text.txt` remotely(on GitHub Pages which has *static web hosting* meaning it does not server side languages like node.js ) ?

if you think this is not possible in **GitHub Pages** please suggest a alternatives method or service (preferably free or cheap) to achieve this.

**Note(Important!):Please read and understand the question and it's provided description before answering ,comment if any clarification is needed.**

Comment: What i understood from your question is basically when you submit it you need to write the value a .txt file , am i correct

Comment: yes i want to write value entered by the user  to a text file

Comment: i think you for this to write to a file you need to have a server side language, with the client side you won't be able to write the input to a text area file, you can use node js for this or any other preferred language for your use case

Comment: github pages still has  probably static web hosting so it may not support node.js like sever side languages